# Создание метода в другом классе с передачей объектов и выведением на консоль

Tags: java

Задача:

1. Создать класс `Student` с параметрами имя и курс;
2. в методе `Main` создать 5 объектов (студентов).

1 метод (show) выводит всю информацию о студентах.

2 метод: нужно передать все 5 студентов и вывести на консоль имена студентов, которые учатся на определенном курсе (номер курса нужно передать в метод, со сканером).

Помогите справиться со вторым методом, никак не получается его создать.

класс Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.name = "Sasha";
        student1.course = 1;
        student1.show();

        Student student2 = new Student();
        student2.name = "Lesha";
        student2.course = 2;
        student2.show();

        Student student3 = new Student();
        student3.name = "Anya";
        student3.course = 3;
        student3.show();

        Student student4 = new Student();
        student4.name = "Tanya";
        student4.course = 4;
        student4.show();

        Student student5 = new Student();
        student5.name = "Ilya";
        student5.course = 5;
        student5.show();

}



    student1.countCourse ();
```

класс Student:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {

    public String name;
    public int course;

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(name + " " + course);
    }

    public void countCourse() {
        int i = course;
        String m = name;

        System.out.println("Введите курс: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (sc.hasNextInt() && sc.nextInt() > 0 && sc.nextInt() <= 5) {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(m);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Введите курс от 1 до 5");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я б немного переделал:

1. Всех студентов поместил бы в список, чтоб в методах `show` и `countCourse` можно было передать этот список, а там внутри пробежаться циклом и вывести нужную информацию.
2. Добавил конструктор, который принимает на вход имя студента и курс. Что упростит, как минимум создание объекта и добавление его в коллекцию.
3. Так как просмотр все инфы о студентах и просмотр всех, кто находится на определенном курсе, по сути, в данном случае, как мне кажется, не относится к конкретном студенту, то методы можно делать статическим.
4. В методе `countCourse` организуем бесконечный цикл, в котором запрашиваем цифирочку (не хватает проверок на ошибки но это на вашей совести будет %)). Как только получаем нужную цифру курса - останавливаем цикл и организуем уже другой цикл, который бежит по переданной коллекции студентом и выводит имя+курс того студент, чей номер совпал с введенным.

Как-то так.

class Student

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by iprogrammer on 13.11.2016.
 */
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int course;

    public Student(String name, int course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public static void show(List<Student> students) {
        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student.name + " " + student.course);
        }
    }

    public static void countCourse(List<Student> students) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int course = 1;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Введите курс (1-5): ");
            course = sc.nextInt(); // Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            if (course >= 1  && course <= 5)
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("Студенты с курса номер " + course + ": ");
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.course == course)
                System.out.println(student.name + " " + student.course);
        }
    }
}
```

метод main

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

students.add(new Student("Sasha", 1));
students.add(new Student("Lesha", 2));
students.add(new Student("Anya", 3));
students.add(new Student("Tanya", 4));
students.add(new Student("Ilya", 5));

Student.show(students);
Student.countCourse(students);
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, в данной задаче под:

> 1 метод (show) выводит всю информацию о студентах. 2 метод: нужно передать все 5 студентов и вывести на консоль имена студентов, которые учатся на определенном курсе (номер курса нужно передать в метод, со сканером).

понимается создание методов в классе `Main`, а не в классе `Student`.

**А теперь по порядку:**

> Задача: создать класс Student с параметрами имя и курс

Данный класс лучше определить таким образом:

```
public class Student {
    private String mName;
    private int mCourse;

    public Student(String name, int course) {
        mName = name;
        mCourse = course;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public int getCourse() {
        return mCourse;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }

    public void setCourse(int course) {
        mCourse = course;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Студент " + mName + " учится на " + mCourse + " курсе.");
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на:

1. Модификатор доступа `private` у полей класса. С этим модификатором поля класса недоступны напрямую извне. Получить/задать значения этих полей можно с помощью соответствующих геттеров/сеттеров. Всегда объявляйте поля класса как `private`, если явно не требуется иное.
2. Префикс `m` у полей класса – этот префикс принято добавлять для всех **нестатических** полей класса (для статических полей префикс будет `s`). По нему сразу можно понять что мы имеем дело с обычным полем класса.
3. Конструктор `Student(String name, int course)`, с помощью которого мы сразу можем создать объект с нужными параметрами.

Соглашусь с Вами, что в классе `Student` целесообразно определить некоторый метод, который будет выводить текстовое представление объекта на экран.

**Далее:**

> в методе Main создать 5 объектов (студентов). 1 метод (show) выводит всю информацию о студентах.

Коль уж задача начального уровня и учебная, то для хранения списка студентов будем использовать простой массив:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[5];

        students[0] = new Student("Вася", 5);
        students[1] = new Student("Петя", 1);
        students[2] = new Student("Аня", 3);
        students[3] = new Student("Федор", 5);
        students[4] = new Student("Маша", 5);

        show(students);
    }

    public static void show(Student[] students) {

        for (int i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
            students[i].print();
        }
    }
}
```

> 2 метод: нужно передать все 5 студентов и вывести на консоль имена студентов, которые учатся на определенном курсе (номер курса нужно передать в метод, со сканером).

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[5];

        students[0] = new Student("Вася", 5);
        students[1] = new Student("Петя", 1);
        students[2] = new Student("Аня", 3);
        students[3] = new Student("Федор", 5);
        students[4] = new Student("Маша", 5);

        System.out.print("Введите курс: ");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            show(students, scanner.nextInt());
        } else {
            System.out.print("Введены некорректные данные!");
        }
    }

    public static void show(Student[] students, int course) {

        for (int i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
            if (students[i].getCourse() == course) {
                students[i].print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```